# Ageing Formula without having column for No of Days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Doc. Date   Aging (days)    Aging class
10/06/2010  1820            121+ Days
09/30/2015  0               0 - 30 Days
09/11/2015  19              0 - 30 Days
09/11/2015  19              0 - 30 Days
09/11/2015  19              0 - 30 Days
09/11/2015  19              0 - 30 Days
```

I want to add ageing grop in Column without having Ageing Days. So can i have help in calculating it in single column instead of 2 steps.

formula for no of days is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H4),"",'Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4)
```

formula for ageing group is

```
=IF(J4<=30,"0 - 30 Days",IF(J4<=60,"31 - 60 Days",IF(J4<=90,"61 - 90 Days",IF(J4<=120,"91 - 120 Days","121+ Days"))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning it is long:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H4),"",IF('Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4<=30,"0 - 30 Days",IF('Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4<=60,"31 - 60 Days",IF('Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4<=90,"61 - 90 Days",IF('Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4<=120,"91 - 120 Days","121+ Days")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively: (without nested if's but need always the same range)

```
=IF(I4="","",CHOOSE(MIN(MAX(TRUNC(('Ex. rate'!$G$2-I4-1)/30)+1,1),5),"0 - 30 Days","31 - 60 Days","61 - 90 Days","91 - 120 Days","121+ Days"))
```

(changed H4 to I4) ...still works perfectly for me. Don't know how it can be wrong... sorry :/

Comment: ...its look good but dont know why its not working for me its only showing 0-30 days. Also instead of I4 it should be H4. I have shifted column and forgot to edit in question.